# Allowing personal github account to push to work github account

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I have two github accounts say work@gmail.com and personal@gmail.com

At my workplace, we have a repo having work@gmail.com as a member having read/write access to that using ssh key that is present in work@gmail.com github account.

Now I deleted the ssh key from work@gmail.com and added it to personal@gmail.com and tried to push something to that repo. But my access was being denied.

Is it possible to get read/write access by having the ssh key pair? 
If yes, then how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to generate a new separate key if you delete one from an account.

But if you want to reuse that key at work (but this time as "personal"), make sure its public key is copied in the personal SSH keys setting page, and that you get a "Welcome Personal" message with:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```